# Facebook Unity3d SDK: Where does FbDebug.Log log?

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I've just started learning writing apps for FB, and have started studying the code for Friend Smash, and I noticed that FbDebug.Log() is sprinkled everywhere.  So where does all this logging go, and where can I see it?

I've been searching everywhere, but I can't find a clue.

Any help is appreciated!

=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a convenience wrapper around `Debug.Log` that would do a `console.log` as well if you do a web player export.  It's probably better to just use `Debug.Log` for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought as much, but nothing comes out of the Chrome console.  I guess I'll try Firefox, just in case.  Thanks again!

Comment: Nope, nothing is coming out of Firefox's console, either.

Comment: They show up when Development Build is turned on.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your post RVC and your answer Brian Jew.

Nice to know that "FBDebug logs" are only shown when development build is turned on.

Is there a way to disable the "Logs" in the Unity Editor mode ? Just to make the console confortable for my colleagues who are developing other functionalities in the game.

Thank you Facebook for this SDK ! Easy to use and it works like a charm :)